On March 1 USD tether
In March, received 10,000 liquid USD Tether on polygon network in my Coinbase wallet, now gone and transaction is missing.  What gives?  Is wallet secure?

Transactions don't just disappear, especially if you checked at least a few minutes after the transaction was included in a block. Maybe you're checking the wrong network or something

You need to provide more information. if you don't see the transactions, then there must be some technical issue with either the wallet or you're checking something else.

It is a well known scam. You received a transfer of a scam token/nft with the same name. When you try to access them you receive an error that the funds are locked and a link to a scam site. The scam site asks money to unlock the tokens/nft. Even if you pay they will never send anything to you.
